# how to pause/resume jobs scheduled using spring task scheduler and task executer

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have implemented a sample spring scheduled task execution application, with an applicationContext as follows,

```
...
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler" executor="myExecuter" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="1" />
<task:executor id="myExecuter" pool-size="10" keep-alive="5" />
...
```

and I have the following Service for scheduling;

```
@Service
public class DataMartListenerJob {
....
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
    public void listenStagingArea() {
    ....
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
    public void listenEULArea() {
    ....
    }
}
```

Now my question is; How can I monitor and manage those two scheduled methods, I mean I want to pause and resume those scheduled methods, on certain circumstances. how can I do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107420/spring-scheduledtask-start-stop-support/7107983#7107983

Comment: Hi Aaron, I thing there should be another way for managing and monitoring the service.