# How to stop a scheduled task that was started using @Scheduled annotation?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have created a simple scheduled task using Spring Framework's [`@Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation.

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
 public void doSomething() {}
```

Now I want to stop this task, when no longer needed.

I know there could be one alternative to check one conditional flag at the start of this method, but this will not stop execution of this method.

Is there anything Spring provides to stop `@Scheduled` task ?

Comment: May be by destroying the bean?

Comment: This could be an option, but I believe there should be another option to do this.

Comment: Have you considered using an Executor?  It's easily canceled in code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: I know, it can be done using executor. Just wondering if spring gives any solution out of the box.

Comment: An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403972/17049932) to suspend/proceed jobs one-by-one

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Option 1: Using a post processor

Supply [`ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) and explicitly invoke [`postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object bean, String beanName)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html#postProcessBeforeDestruction-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-), for the bean whose scheduling should be stopped.

#### Option 2: Maintaining a map of target beans to its Future

```
private final Map<Object, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledTasks =
        new IdentityHashMap<>();

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
public void fixedRateJob() {
    System.out.println("Something to be done every 2 secs");
}

@Bean
public TaskScheduler poolScheduler() {
    return new CustomTaskScheduler();
}

class CustomTaskScheduler extends ThreadPoolTaskScheduler {

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, period);

        ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task;
        scheduledTasks.put(runnable.getTarget(), future);

        return future;
    }

    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startTime, period);

        ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task;
        scheduledTasks.put(runnable.getTarget(), future);

        return future;
    }
}
```

When the scheduling for a bean has to be stopped, you can lookup the map to get the corresponding [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to it and explicitly cancel it.

Comment: second option is fine, could you please elaborate first option more.

Comment: Option 2 is ok. I notice that Custom Scheduler may not called because of another scheduler already declared. I faced in case of using websocket.

Comment: What if we need to start the scheduler again?

Comment: @NeoPham I had similar issue, in that case `public TaskScheduler poolScheduler()` shoud have additional `@Primary` annotation.

Comment: Note that second option is not thread-safe. One should synchronize access to a map

Comment: Where is scheduledTasks variable defined in the class ?

Comment: As a class variable, the first line

Answer (score 21):

Here is an example where we can stop , start , and list also all the scheduled running tasks:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

private static final String SCHEDULED_TASKS = "scheduledTasks";

@Autowired
private ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;

@Autowired
private ScheduledTasks scheduledTasks;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@GetMapping(value = "/stopScheduler")
public String stopSchedule(){
    postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(scheduledTasks, SCHEDULED_TASKS);
    return "OK";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/startScheduler")
public String startSchedule(){
    postProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(scheduledTasks, SCHEDULED_TASKS);
    return "OK";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/listScheduler")
public String listSchedules() throws JsonProcessingException{
    Set<ScheduledTask> setTasks = postProcessor.getScheduledTasks();
    if(!setTasks.isEmpty()){
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(setTasks);
    }else{
        return "No running tasks !";
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction() method is not present. I am using Spring 4.1.7

Comment: Just one warning: multple Invocations of `postProcessAfterInitialization(..)` will schedule same tasks multiple times.

Comment: will the /startScheduler call trigger the scheduler right away ignoring the cross expression?

Answer (score 8):

Some time ago I had this requirement in my project that any component should be able to create a new scheduled task or to stop the scheduler (all tasks). So I did something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan
@Component
public class CentralScheduler {

    private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext CONTEXT = null;

    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

    public static CentralScheduler getInstance() {
        if (!isValidBean()) {
            CONTEXT = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CentralScheduler.class);
        }

        return CONTEXT.getBean(CentralScheduler.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    }

    public void start(Runnable task, String scheduleExpression) throws Exception {
        scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger(scheduleExpression));
    }

    public void start(Runnable task, Long delay) throws Exception {
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, delay);
    }

    public void stopAll() {
        scheduler.shutdown();
        CONTEXT.close();
    }

    private static boolean isValidBean() {
        if (CONTEXT == null || !CONTEXT.isActive()) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            CONTEXT.getBean(CentralScheduler.class);
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

So I can do things like

```
Runnable task = new MyTask();
CentralScheduler.getInstance().start(task, 30_000L);
CentralScheduler.getInstance().stopAll();
```

Have in mind that, for some reasons, I did it without having to worry about concurrency. There should be some synchronization otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

A working example implementation of @Mahesh 's Option 1, using `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(bean, beanName)`.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;


public class ScheduledTaskExample implements ApplicationContextAware, BeanNameAware
{

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private String             beanName;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void someTask()
    {
        /* Do stuff */

        if (stopScheduledTaskCondition)
        {
            stopScheduledTask();
        }
    }

    private void stopScheduledTask()
    {
        ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean = applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class);
        bean.postProcessBeforeDestruction(this, beanName);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName)
    {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't stop when stopScheduledTaskCondition becomes false.

Comment: Hi @menoktaokan, `stopScheduledTask();` is executed when `stopScheduledTaskCondition` becomes `true`.

Comment: Same as @menoktaokan

Answer (score 6):

Another approach that I have not found yet. Simple, clear and thread safe.

1. In your configuration class add annotation:

   `@EnableScheduling`
2. This and next step in your class where you need start/stop scheduled task inject:

   `@Autowired TaskScheduler taskScheduler;`
3. Set fields:

   ```
    private ScheduledFuture yourTaskState;
    private long fixedRate = 1000L;
   ```
4. Create inner class that execute scheduled tasks eg.:

   ```
    class ScheduledTaskExecutor implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
          // task to be executed
        }
    }
   ```
5. Add start() method:

   ```
    public void start(){
        yourTaskState = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledTaskExecutor(), fixedRate);
    }
   ```
6. Add stop() method:

   ```
    public void stop(){
        yourTaskState.cancel(false);
    }
   ```

TaskScheduler provide other common way for scheduling like: cron or delay.

ScheduledFuture provide also `isCancelled();`

Answer (score 5):

There is a bit of ambiguity in this question

1. When you say "stop this task", did you mean to stop in such a way that it's later recoverable (if yes, programmatically, using a condition which arises with in the same app? or external condition?)
2. Are you running any other tasks in the same context? (Possibility of shutting down the entire app rather than a task) -- You can make use of actuator.shutdown endpoint in this scenario

My best guess is, you are looking to shutdown a task using a condition that may arise with in the same app, in a recoverable fashion. I will try to answer based on this assumption.

This is the [simplest possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18406954/6785908) solution that I can think of, However I will make some improvements like early return rather than **nested if**s

```
@Component
public class SomeScheduledJob implements Job {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeScheduledJob.class);

    @Value("${jobs.mediafiles.imagesPurgeJob.enable}")
    private boolean imagesPurgeJobEnable;

    @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "${jobs.mediafiles.imagesPurgeJob.schedule}")
    public void execute() {

        if(!imagesPurgeJobEnable){
            return;
        }
        Do your conditional job here...
   }
```

Properties for the above code

```
jobs.mediafiles.imagesPurgeJob.enable=true or false
jobs.mediafiles.imagesPurgeJob.schedule=0 0 0/12 * * ?
```

Comment: I have already tried this thing, this thing won't stop the scheduler.

Answer (score 5):

Minimalist answer:
@mahesh's option 1, expanded here in minimal form for convenience, will irreversibly cancel all scheduled tasks on this bean:

```
@Autowired
private ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
public void doSomething() {}

public void stopThis() {
    postProcessBeforeDestruction(this, "")
}
```

Alternatively, this will irreversibly cancel all tasks on *all* beans:

```
@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
public void doSomething() {}

public void stopAll() {
    scheduler.shutdown();
}
```

Thanks, all the previous responders, for solving this one for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scheduled

When spring process `Scheduled`, it will iterate each method annotated this annotation and organize tasks by beans as the following source shows:

```
private final Map<Object, Set<ScheduledTask>> scheduledTasks =
        new IdentityHashMap<Object, Set<ScheduledTask>>(16);
```

#### Cancel

If you just want to cancel the a repeated scheduled task, you can just do like following (here is a [runnable demo](https://github.com/zzt93/Daily-pracitce/tree/master/java/knowledge/schedule) in my repo):

```
@Autowired
private ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;
@Autowired
private TestSchedule testSchedule;

public void later() {
    postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(test, "testSchedule");
}
```

#### Notice

It will find this beans's `ScheduledTask` and cancel it one by one. What should be noticed is it will also stopping the current running method (as `postProcessBeforeDestruction` source shows).

```
    synchronized (this.scheduledTasks) {
        tasks = this.scheduledTasks.remove(bean); // remove from future running
    }
    if (tasks != null) {
        for (ScheduledTask task : tasks) {
            task.cancel(); // cancel current running method
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Define a custom annotation like below.

```
@Documented
@Retention (RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ScheduledSwitch {
    // do nothing
}
```

Define a class implements org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.

```
public class ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessorCustom 
    extends ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

    @Value(value = "${prevent.scheduled.tasks:false}")
    private boolean preventScheduledTasks;

    private Map<Object, String> beans = new HashMap<>();

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {
        ScheduledSwitch switch = AopProxyUtils.ultimateTargetClass(bean)
            .getAnnotation(ScheduledSwitch.class);
        if (null != switch) {
            beans.put(bean, beanName);
            if (preventScheduledTasks) {
                return bean;
            }
        }
        return super.postProcessAfterInitialization(bean, beanName);
    }

    public void stop() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<Object, String> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
                postProcessBeforeDestruction(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<Object, String> entry : beans.entrySet()) {
                if (!requiresDestruction(entry.getKey())) {
                    super.postProcessAfterInitialization(
                        entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Replace ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean by the custom bean in configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class ScheduledConfig {

    @Bean(name = TaskManagementConfigUtils.SCHEDULED_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    public ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor scheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessorCustom();
    }

}
```

Add @ScheduledSwitch annotation to the beans that you want to prevent or stop @Scheduled tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Using `@conditional` will help you check a value from condition method, if it's true? run the scheduler. else don't run.

First: create your condition class that implements the Condition interface and its `matches` method

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition{

public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetaData metadata) {

// here implement your condition using if-else or checking another object 
// or call another method that can return boolean value
//return boolean value : true or false 

return true;
}
}
```

Then, back to your configuration or service class where you have the `@Scheduled`

```
@Service
@Conditional(value = MyCondition.class)
// this Service will only run if the condition is true 
public class scheduledTask {


// the @Scheduled method should be void
@Scheduled(fixedRate= 5000)
public void task(){
System.out.println(" This is scheduled task started....");
}

}
```

This definitely worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import org.redisson.liveobject.misc.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.CronTask;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTask;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.util.Collections.emptySet;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import org.redisson.liveobject.misc.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.CronTask;
import org.springframework.scheduling.config.ScheduledTask;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.util.Collections.emptySet;

/**
 * @author uhfun
 */
@Component
public class ConfigurableScheduler {
    private final InnerScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;

    public ConfigurableScheduler(InnerScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor) {
        this.postProcessor = postProcessor;
    }

    public void registerScheduleTask(String cron, Method method, Object target) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = Maps.newHashMap();
        attributes.put("cron", cron);
        Scheduled scheduled = AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotation(attributes, Scheduled.class, null);
        postProcessor.registerScheduleTask(scheduled, method, target);
    }

    public void unregister(String cron, Object target) {
        postProcessor.unregister(target, cron);
    }

    @Component
    public static class InnerScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor extends ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

        private final Map<Object, Set<ScheduledTask>> scheduledTasksMap;

        public InnerScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
            scheduledTasksMap = ClassUtils.getField(this, "scheduledTasks");
        }

        public void registerScheduleTask(Scheduled scheduled, Method method, Object bean) {
            super.processScheduled(scheduled, method, bean);
        }

        public void unregister(Object bean, String cron) {
            synchronized (scheduledTasksMap) {
                Set<ScheduledTask> tasks = getScheduledTasks();
                for (ScheduledTask task : tasks) {
                    if (task.getTask() instanceof CronTask
                            && ((CronTask) task.getTask()).getExpression().equals(cron)) {
                        task.cancel();
                        scheduledTasksMap.getOrDefault(bean, emptySet()).remove(task);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and explain why your answer is better than the other answers.

Answer (score -5):

How about using `System.exit(1)`?
It is simple and works.

Comment: welcome to the community Adam, please try to read the questions complete and understand the requirements then if you know the answer , write yours.
answers need to be more detailed than your one line answer also try to have a reference for your answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That has the downside of stopping the entire application, rather than just the one scheduled bean.  It seems fairly implied that the goal is to keep the application running, and only stop the one scheduled task.