# programatically shut down spring @scheduled task

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot + spring scheduler. I want to shut down the scheduler after some condition is met. Please let me know how to make it possible.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);
    static int a=0;
    @Autowired ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        if(a==5)
        {
            //I need code to stop this here
        }
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a scheduled task that was started using @Scheduled annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/how-to-stop-a-scheduled-task-that-was-started-using-scheduled-annotation)

Comment: Thanks Michael... The solution worked out for me.