# How wait @Scheduled till previous task is not finished?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to wail my scheduler till my task is complete.if there is time for second schedule execution, it has to wait till previous task is not complete.
I m using @Schedule in java Boot application.
I want to insert data into data base in every 5 minutes but i want to hold my schedule till the inset data is not complete still there is a time for second execution.Demo Code

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
    public void scheduleTaskWithFixedRate() {
        logger.info("Fixed Rate Task :: Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()) );
    }
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/how-to-stop-a-scheduled-task-that-was-started-using-scheduled-annotation)

Comment: Check link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks and readout point number 5.

Answer (score 17):

Use `fixedDelay`

**fixedRate :** makes Spring run the task at every n millisecond.

**fixedDelay :** specifically controls the next task execution time by delaying next task by n millisecond after the last execution finishes.

In code:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
public void updateEmployeeInventory(){
    
}    

@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void updateEmployeeInventory(){
   
}
```

Comment: if the task block the execute thread，`fixedRate` or `fixedDelay` has no  difference？

Comment: @TongChen There is a difference. Let's say you blocked the thread for 5 Min. So next schedule will execute only after 5 Min 5 sec as per above configuration. "when the last execution finishes. "

Comment: What about cron?

Comment: The part about `fixedRate` is in disagreement with the Baeldung article posted which says "Note that scheduled tasks don't run in parallel by default. So even if we used fixedRate, the next task won't be invoked until the previous one is done."

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `fixedRate`, use `fixedDelay`:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
```

The task will run `fixedDelay` milliseconds one after another

> Execute the annotated method with a fixed period in milliseconds between the end of the last invocation and the start of the next.

Comment: I make one demo，`fixedRate` or `fixedDelay` is all ok，why？:

Comment: Can some one please answer does spring "cron expression" waits for tasks to finish like "fixedDelay" does ?

Comment: @ALI were you able to get the answer for the "cron expression"?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
```

You should use the **initialDelay** prop with @scheduled annotation inorder to wait for sometime.