# stop and start springboot scheduler service on demand

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler

I was following below article to start & stop scheduler.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50216003/4770397

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

private static final String SCHEDULED_TASKS = "scheduledTasks";

@Autowired
private ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;

@Autowired
private ScheduledTasks scheduledTasks;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@GetMapping(value = "/stopScheduler")
public String stopSchedule(){
    postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(scheduledTasks, SCHEDULED_TASKS);
    return "OK";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/startScheduler")
public String startSchedule(){
    postProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(scheduledTasks, SCHEDULED_TASKS);
    return "OK";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/listScheduler")
public String listSchedules() throws JsonProcessingException{
    Set<ScheduledTask> setTasks = postProcessor.getScheduledTasks();
    if(!setTasks.isEmpty()){
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(setTasks);
    }else{
        return "No running tasks !";
    }
}
```

But **`postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction()` method** is unavailable in my project.
please help.

Comment: Can you please send the logs

Comment: I am getting **postProcessBeforeDestruction()** not available.

Comment: Which version of spring boot are you using? Seems like method this was introduced in Spring Framework 5

Comment: I am using 4.1.7