# Scheduled Task Cancel without interrupt

Tags: spring-boot, completable-future, spring-scheduled

I read [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/how-to-stop-a-scheduled-task-that-was-started-using-scheduled-annotation)
My question is how to cancel it without interrupt. The cancel method of scheduled task is without any parameter and it internally calls **((ScheduledFuture)this.future).cancel(true)**, which might interrupt the current task.

In my case I don't use Scheduled annotation, instead programmatically create it using **taskRegistrar.scheduleFixedRateTask(fixedRateTask)** which returns **ScheduledTask**. Hence I have reference to ScheduledTask and I can invoke cancel() whenever I need. But with the risk of interrupting it. Since the future is package private, I cannot access **scheduledTask.future.cancel(false)**.

Is there another way?

Comment: I wanted to control the fixed interval, hence I initially opted scheduleAtFixedRateTask. Later I managed to run it with Scheduled annotation with the help of ApplicationListener<RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent>. Please check this sample app to know how it works https://github.com/winster/SpringSchedulerDynamic