# How to trigger dynamic scheduling jobs in Java and cancel them?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I invoke a job dynamatically and cancel them at ease? Can I trigger a delayed task that runs at a specific moment, and cancel them if the moment has not passed by, just behaving like the alarm clock?

Comment: Currently, I am working on a function which allows clients to set the execution time of tasks at their will. Clients can also cancel these tasks if the time has not arrived. I am puzzled about how to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a scheduled task that was started using @Scheduled annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/how-to-stop-a-scheduled-task-that-was-started-using-scheduled-annotation)

Comment: @MegaMbo That annotation can only create fixed rated or CRON type tasks. In my scene, the time submitted by clients are not regular, it may be a minute later, 15 minutes later, an hour later or even days later. And as far as I know, I cannot cancel the tasks submitted if I use the annotation.

Comment: I would persist the cron in a table and poll for the value so you can set up that cron or cancel it.

Comment: @burm87 I think it  is a little bit costly to build cron expression for tasks that just run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another enterprise job-scheduling framework for this task, which is called [PowerJob](https://github.com/PowerJob/PowerJob). With the OpenAPI it provides, delayed tasks could be easily created and canceled.   Source codes are available [here](https://github.com/jjnnzb/alarm-clock).
Firstly, init the project with its guidance.

Then, create our own project. We will need both PowerJob-worker and PowerJob-client.
So dependencies in Pom file is like:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kfcfans</groupId>
            <artifactId>powerjob-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kfcfans</groupId>
            <artifactId>powerjob-worker-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.75</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Entities used:

Response class:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response {
    private Integer code;
    private String message;
    private JSONObject info;
    
    public static Response success(JSONObject data) {
        return Response.builder().code(200).message("success").info(data).build();
    }
    
    public static Response error(JSONObject data) {
        return Response.builder().code(500).message("fail").info(data).build();
    }
}
```

The Alarm class:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class AlarmClock {
    private Long id;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "username should not be blank.")
    private String username;
    
    private String clockName;
    
    @NotNull(message = "Delay should not be null.")
    private Long delayMillis;
    
    private Long instanceId;
    
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "GMT+8")
    private LocalDateTime createTime;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return JSON.toJSONStringWithDateFormat(this, JSON.DEFFAULT_DATE_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

The task is like:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.worker.core.processor.ProcessResult;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.worker.core.processor.TaskContext;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.worker.core.processor.sdk.BasicProcessor;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.worker.log.OmsLogger;
import com.github.powerjobdemo.entity.AlarmClock;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Component
public class AlarmClockTask implements BasicProcessor {
    
    public static final DateTimeFormatter STANDARD_DATE_TIME = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    
    @Override
    public ProcessResult process(TaskContext taskContext) throws Exception {
        OmsLogger omsLogger = taskContext.getOmsLogger();
        String instanceParams = taskContext.getInstanceParams();
        omsLogger.info("instance params:{}", instanceParams);
        AlarmClock alarmClock = JSON.parseObject(instanceParams, AlarmClock.class);
        assert alarmClock != null;
        String username = alarmClock.getUsername();
        omsLogger.info("Current time is:{}", STANDARD_DATE_TIME.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
        omsLogger.info("Clock info: id:{}, name:{}, creator:{}", alarmClock.getId(), alarmClock.getClockName(), username);
        return new ProcessResult(true, String.format("User: %s running an alarm clock.", username));
    }
}
```

Service interface is like:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.github.powerjobdemo.entity.AlarmClock;

public interface ClockService {
    /**
     * Add alarm clock.
     *
     * @param alarmClock alarm clock
     * @return json
     */
    JSONObject addAlarmClock(AlarmClock alarmClock);
    
    /**
     * Cancel alarm clock.
     *
     * @param alarmClock alarm clock
     */
    JSONObject cancelAlarmClock(AlarmClock alarmClock);
    
    /**
     * Query all alarm clocks.
     *
     * @param username username
     * @return list
     */
    JSONObject queryAll(String username);
}
```

Service impl class is like:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.client.OhMyClient;
import com.github.kfcfans.powerjob.common.response.ResultDTO;
import com.github.powerjobdemo.entity.AlarmClock;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class ClockServiceImpl implements ClockService {
    
    public static final DateTimeFormatter CLOCK_NAME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
    
    private static final List<AlarmClock> alarmClockList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    
    private final AtomicLong clockCount = new AtomicLong();
    
    @Resource
    private OhMyClient ohMyClient;
    
    @Value("${powerjob.task.id}")
    private Long taskId;
    
    @Override
    public JSONObject addAlarmClock(AlarmClock alarmClock) {
        String formattedName = CLOCK_NAME_FORMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        alarmClock.setClockName("Clock-" + formattedName);
        long id = clockCount.addAndGet(1L);
        alarmClock.setCreateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        Long delayMillis = alarmClock.getDelayMillis();
        ResultDTO<Long> longResultDTO = ohMyClient.runJob(taskId, alarmClock.toString(), delayMillis);
        alarmClock.setInstanceId(longResultDTO.getData());
        alarmClockList.add(alarmClock);
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("id", id);
        return data;
    }
    
    @Override
    public JSONObject cancelAlarmClock(AlarmClock alarmClock) {
        Long instanceId = alarmClock.getInstanceId();
        assert instanceId != null;
        ohMyClient.cancelInstance(instanceId);
        alarmClockList.removeIf(clock -> Objects.equals(instanceId, clock.getInstanceId()));
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("instanceId", instanceId);
        return data;
    }
    
    @Override
    public JSONObject queryAll(String username) {
        List<AlarmClock> clockList = alarmClockList.stream()
                .filter(alarmClock -> StringUtils.equals(alarmClock.getUsername(), username))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("data", clockList);
        data.put("count", clockList.size());
        return data;
    }
}
```

And finally, controller is like:

```java
import com.github.powerjobdemo.entity.AlarmClock;
import com.github.powerjobdemo.entity.Response;
import com.github.powerjobdemo.service.ClockService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class AlarmClockController {
    
    @Resource
    private ClockService clockService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/alarm/clock/add")
    public Response addAlarmClock(@RequestBody AlarmClock alarmClock) {
        return Response.success(clockService.addAlarmClock(alarmClock));
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/alarm/clock/cancel")
    public Response cancelAlarmClock(@RequestBody AlarmClock alarmClock) {
        return Response.success(clockService.cancelAlarmClock(alarmClock));
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/v1/alarm/clock/query")
    public Response queryAlarmClock(@RequestParam String username) {
        return Response.success(clockService.queryAll(username));
    }
}
```

So we could post the api `/api/v1/alarm/clock/add` for adding new alarm clock. For example, create an alarm clock that runs 600 seconds later.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/alarm/clock/add' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "username": "Jimmy",
  "delayMillis": 600000
}'
```

Response is like:

```json
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "info": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

And then query.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/alarm/clock/query?username=Jimmy'
```

Response is like:

```json
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "info": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "Jimmy",
                "clockName": "Clock-20210118-002804",
                "delayMillis": 600000,
                "instanceId": 231210525113975104,
                "createTime": "2021-01-18 00:28:04"
            }
        ],
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

To cancel the clock:

Post the cancel API:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/alarm/clock/cancel' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"instanceId": "231210525113975104"}'
```

The response:

```json
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "info": {
        "instanceId": 231210525113975104
    }
}
```

We could see all the instances on the web page, which is helpful.
[Task instance list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7LUn.png)

Answer (score 1):

`Quartz` is a good scheduling library that has lots of capabilities like run many jobs and simple triggers, cron triggers simultaneously in a single machine or clustered. Also, it can be run on memory or persisting on a database. For more details [Scheduling in Spring with Quartz](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule)

I have created a basic setup that is focused on scheduling concept. There are there methods to create, list and kill jobs. It is added that `Thread.sleep` for simulating a long-running job.

### Scenario

Create a new job

```
POST http://localhost:8080/start/foo

Trigger is created. Job name is 'foo-1609322783667'
```

List triggers by job

```
GET http://localhost:8080/list/foo

[
    "foo-1609322783667"
]
```

Kill the running job

```
DELETE http://localhost:8080/kill/foo

Job is interrupted
```

Console output:

```
2020-12-30 13:06:23.671  INFO 920 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] com.example.demo.HomeController          : Job is created. It will be triggered at Wed Dec 30 13:06:28 EET 2020
2020-12-30 13:06:28.681  INFO 920 --- [eduler_Worker-1] com.example.demo.job.FooJob              : Job started DEFAULT.foo-1609322783667
2020-12-30 13:06:51.109  INFO 920 --- [eduler_Worker-1] com.example.demo.job.FooJob              : Job is interrupted DEFAULT.foo-1609322783667
2020-12-30 13:06:51.109  INFO 920 --- [eduler_Worker-1] com.example.demo.job.FooJob              : Job completed DEFAULT.foo-1609322783667
```

### Source Code

pom.xml (if you are using `Gradle`, you can change definitions on `build.gradle`)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=memory
```

JobConfig

```java
@Configuration
public class JobConfig {
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean fooJobDetail() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(FooJob.class);
        jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetailFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean barJobDetail() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(BarJob.class);
        jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetailFactory;
    }
}
```

BarJob

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class BarJob implements InterruptableJob {
    private Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("Job started {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50_000); // wait 50 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.info("Job is interrupted {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        log.info("Job completed {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
}
```

FooJob

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class FooJob implements InterruptableJob {
    private Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        log.info("Job started {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100_000); // wait 100 seconds
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.info("Job is interrupted {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        log.info("Job completed {}", jobExecutionContext.getTrigger().getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

HomeController

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("fooJobDetail")
    private JobDetail fooJobDetail;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("barJobDetail")
    private JobDetail barJobDetail;

    @PostMapping("/start/{jobName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> startJob(@PathVariable("jobName") String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
        Optional<JobDetail> jobDetail = parseJob(jobName);
        if (!jobDetail.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid job name");
        }

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail.get())
                .withIdentity(jobName + "-" + new Date().getTime()) // unique name
                .startAt(Date.from(Instant.now().plusSeconds(5)))   // starts 5 seconds later
                .build();

        Date date = scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
        log.info("Job is created. It will be triggered at {}", date);

        return ResponseEntity.ok("Trigger is created. Job name is '" + trigger.getKey().getName() + "'");
    }

    /**
     * Find the job by job name
     */
    private Optional<JobDetail> parseJob(String jobName) {
        if ("foo".equals(jobName)) {
            return Optional.of(fooJobDetail);
        } else if ("bar".equals(jobName)) {
            return Optional.of(barJobDetail);
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @GetMapping("/list/{jobName}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> listTriggers(@PathVariable("jobName") String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
        Optional<JobDetail> jobDetail = parseJob(jobName);
        if (!jobDetail.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        List<String> triggers = scheduler.getTriggersOfJob(jobDetail.get().getKey()).stream()
                .map(t -> t.getKey().getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(triggers);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/kill/{jobName}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> killTrigger(@PathVariable("jobName") String jobName) throws SchedulerException {
        Optional<JobDetail> jobDetail = parseJob(jobName);
        if (!jobDetail.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
        scheduler.interrupt(jobDetail.get().getKey());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Job is interrupted");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind help. I have sovled my problem using another scheduling framework called [PowerJob](https://github.com/PowerJob/PowerJob), the answer can be seen below. The framework is more friendly with the web page and supports a lot of fancy tasks.