# Create cron job and stop it without @Scheduled Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I am using `@Scheduled` annotation to initialize a task scheduled in my Spring Boot project.

```
@Override
@Scheduled(cron = "#{scanningTime}")
public void execution() {
    invitePlanScanner();
}
```

But I'm have difficulty to stopping it at runtime. My idea is to initialize a cron job in addition to using annotations that able to dynamically use the methods of the library. But after a period of research, I don't see that java provides a specific way to initialize a job with cron schedule along with a stop method.

Any one have an idea for this problem?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Are you asking on how to schedule tasks in java without Spring (`ScheduledExecutorService`) or how to [make a thread interruptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do)?

Comment: @daniu I mean I use annotation to start a cron job but I can't stop it during runtime. So I came up with an idea to use some library in addition to initializing that job with annotation. But I can't find a specific method to run the cron job and stop it at runtime (may be in catch block, or an api to stop it)

Comment: You can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644141/how-to-stop-a-scheduled-task-that-was-started-using-scheduled-annotation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "ThreadPoolTaskScheduler".

```
ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = taskScheduler.schedule(
  createRunnable(),
  new PeriodicTrigger(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
);
schedule.cancel(true);
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` does not implement from `ScheduledFuture<?>`. How you can declare like that?

Comment: @ThànhĐặng The return type of "schedule" is ScheduledFuture<?>. The signature is "public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, Trigger trigger)"